# Routing in mvc and link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have these routing in global.asax

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] {"MVCTemplateProject.Controllers"}
            );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Post",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Title}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Post", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Title = UrlParameter.Optional},
            namespaces: new[] {"MVCTemplateProject.Controllers"}
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetPostByCategoryName",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{CategoryName}",
            defaults:
                new {controller = "Post", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, CategoryName = UrlParameter.Optional},
            namespaces: new[] {"MVCTemplateProject.Controllers"}
            );
```

i have a link with this href http://mysite.com/Post/GetPostsByTagId/3/a
if i click on the line and redirect to page that has same link with same address
so my link has this  address
http://mysite.com/Post/GetPostsByTagId/3/a/2/asdasd
and raise error
this is my link syntax

```
   <a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Post.ActionNames.GetPostsByCategoryId,MVC.Post.Name)\@category.Id\@category.Name.ToSeoUrl()">@category.Name</a>
```

Comment: Where is this path in config?

Comment: Have you tried adding another route that will know how to handle the second (longer) url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may not completely answer your question, but it should help you along.

**URL.Action()**

First a small thing. You linked URL is using backslahes, whereas slashes should be used. So change

```
 <a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Post.ActionNames.GetPostsByCategoryId,MVC.Post.Name)\@category.Id\@category.Name.ToSeoUrl()">@category.Name</a>
```

to

```
 <a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Post.ActionNames.GetPostsByCategoryId,MVC.Post.Name)/@category.Id/@category.Name.ToSeoUrl()">@category.Name</a>
```

For us to help you, please also show what the current result is.

Also in this part, you will want to use [route values for the additional url parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), so that the MVC routing system can sort out where to put what in your SEO-optimised URL. So then it would look something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.Post.ActionNames.GetPostsByCategoryId,MVC.Post.Name, new { id = category.Id, CategoryName = category.Name.ToSeoUrl() })">@category.Name</a>
```

**MVC Routing**

The main part about your question is related to routing. The way the current routes are set up is that the first one will catch *everything* because all parameters in that route are optional.

When you use `Url.Action()` or when a request is being matched against the routes, the first possibility which matches will be used. It will *not* try to find the best match possible.

So the idea is that you will have to place your most specific routes on top. If they match, they're used, if not, it will continue, until eventually ending up in, usually, a catch-all route, like the one that MVC automatically puts in for you.

Your second and third routes still have their parameters optional. Didn't you actually mean that for those routes, the parameters should be made required?

The second one seems a bit more specific than the third one, as it has 4 parameters, versus 3 for the other one. The first seems to be inteded as the catch-all route.

And as a last part, if you specify a default value, that can still be replace by anything else. So if you want it to match just the `PostController`, you have to put it in the `url`, not the `defaults`.

This would result in the following altered routing rules:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Post",
    url: "Post/Index/{id}/{Title}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] {"MVCTemplateProject.Controllers"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetPostByCategoryName",
    url: "Post/GetPostByCategoryName/{CategoryName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "GetPostByCategoryName" },
    namespaces: new[] {"MVCTemplateProject.Controllers"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] {"MVCTemplateProject.Controllers"}
);
```

You can see, the `url`s are being fixed for the `PostController`, but the route doesn't magically know what the controller and action will be, so you will still have to specify those in your `defaults`.

**Conclusion**

Try and understand the MVC routing system a bit more. This explanation should help you on your way a bit. Or it might even help you solve your problem already.

It is not entirely clear (if this is) what you needed. If you elaborate your question, I might elaborate my answer.